# Uploading file gives error

Tags: php, excel, laravel-5.1

I need to upload `.xlsx` file to database . I have 3 column in db `value,pin_num,password_num`. my code is like this

```
 public function import(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->hasFile('file'))
        {
            $files = $request->file('file');

            $file = fopen($files, "r");
            while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                 $excel = new Excel;
                 $excel->value = $emapData[0];
                 $excel->pin_num = $emapData[1];
                 $excel->password_num = $emapData[2];

                 $excel->save();

            }

        }
       return Redirect::to('dashboard/file/view');
```

This upload .csvfile successfullly but it gives error on uploading.xlsx file Error is like this

```
Undefined offset: 1
in AdminController.php line 36
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined offset: 1', '/var/www/html/project/app/Http/Controllers/Backend/Admin/AdminController.php', '36', array('request' => object(Request), 'files' => object(UploadedFile), 'file' => resource, 'emapData' => array('PK!q9+p��[Content_Types].xml ��(�̔MN�0��H�!�%n��j�?K��ؓƪc[���g��'), 'excel' => object(Excel))) in AdminController.php line 36
```

on dd($emapData); it gives below result

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => b"PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x06\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00!\x00q\x0E9+p\x01\x00\x00 \x05\x00\x00\x13\x00Û\x01[Content_Types].xml ¢×\x01( \x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Ì”MNÃ0\x10…÷HÜ!ò\x16%n‹„\x10jÚ\x05?K¨\x04\x1CÀØ“Æªc[\x1E·´·g’Ð"
]
```

How to upload xlsx file?How to modify this code?

Comment: have you done a `print_r($emapData)` to see what is there?

Comment: @Sean it gives Array ( [0] => PK!q9+p��[Content_Types].xml ��(�̔MN�0��H�!�%n��j�?K��ؓƪc[���g�� ) on print_r($emapData)

Comment: It looks like your CSV file is broken. Is it correct that there is something like `PK!q9+p...` in the first column of your CSV?

Comment: @mapek i have no PK!q9+p... in the first column of .xlsx file .i have value like this 001,002 and so on